# Swagger 3 Open API doesn't display api details with same endpoint but with different parameter

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-3.0

I am working on Springboot 2.6.8 version and integrating Swagger 3 using springdoc-open-ui dependency. Integration works fine and Swagger-ui.html displays the API documentation. But I have multiple API's with same endpoint with different parameters. Due to this Swagger-ui not able to differentiate with those endpoint and doesn't show any of them on the UI.

Endpoint:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/title/find", params= {"provider", "offerEnd"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Title> AMethodName(@RequestParam final String provider, @RequestParam final String offerEnd) {

} 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/title/find", params = {"channel","offerStart"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Title> BMethodName(@RequestParam final String channel, @RequestParam final List<String> offerStart) {
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/title/find", params= {"provider","offerStart","titleBrief"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Title> CMethodName(@RequestParam final List<String> provider, @RequestParam final List<String> offerStart, @RequestParam final String titleBrief) {
}
```

Swagger Dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
<version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Swagger UI only able to display only one of "/title/find" out of those.
Can you tell me what customization i need to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger 3 Open API  does not support conditional parameters.(same endpoint)

See here.
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256